# Send info to a php page using jQuery and $.get

Tags: php, jquery

Here's my problem: I'm using the datepicker form jQuery UI for selecting a date and after the date is selected I'm trying to send the date selected to a php file!
Here's what I've tried but does not work:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $.get("myPhpFile.php",{ data: dateText },
                    function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                    }

      );});
```

After the date is selected - the alert box apears but nothing seems to happen!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do not send `data` like this. rather send via querystring i.e.`"myPhpFile.php?data="+dateText` . This will be received in php as `$_GET['data']`

Comment: "the alert box apears but nothing seems to happen" what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Your Javascript code seems to be correct. What does your PHP code look like? Does `myPhpFile.php` return anything?

Comment: @LeleDumbo I was hoping that the I will be redirected to the myPHPFile.php ;)

Comment: @Demnogonis <?php
$buffer_data['date'] = $_POST['data'];
echo $buffer_data['date'];
?> This is what I have in my php file

Comment: @Imdad The above code will work as well, you can optionally pass a map object that will be converted to a query string by jQ

Comment: @Alin You should use `$buffer_data['date'] = $_GET['data'];`. The clue is in the jQ method name (`$.get`)

Comment: @DaveRandom You are right! But it still doen't happen anything! In the alert box I get the date selected but I'm still not redirected to my file! It only apears the message box and that's it!

Comment: The code above does not do any kind of redirecting - I don't think you need `$.get` at all, I think you want `$("#datepicker").datepicker({ onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { window.location.href = 'myPhpFile.php?data='+encodeURIComponent(dateText); } });`

Comment: you mistinterpret $.get then, it does ajax request to your page (myPhpFile.php) and gets the response from the 3rd argument. it won't redirect you anywhere, unless your response is a meta-redirection html (and it has to be executed as well) or you use DOM to redirect based on the response

Comment: You could use JQuery.post, to use $_POST['data'] on your php file, but it does not "Redirect" you to that page... 

`$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
    jQuery.post("myPhpFile.php",{data: dateText}); }
});`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has one mismatch curly bracket maybe that is causing the problem.Try it

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $.get("myPhpFile.php",{ data: dateText },
                    function(ajaxdata) {
                            alert(ajaxdata);
                    });
                    }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
    $.post("myPhpFile.php",{ data: dateText },
                function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                }
         )}});
```

Then in the PHP:

```
    $date = $_POST['data'];​​
    // do your math with data
    echo $result;
```

`$result` should be picked up by your `alert()`.

If you want to use GET, use:

```
$.get("myPhpFile.php?data="+dateText,function () ...}
```

Pay attention to brackets, they were wrong in your example